# Python boto ec2 - Deleting snapshots of an AMI

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I want to delete an AMI along with all the snapshots associated with it. According to the docs:

```
deregister_image(image_id, delete_snapshot=True)
Unregister an AMI.

Parameters: 
image_id (string) – the ID of the Image to unregister
delete_snapshot (bool) – Set to True if we should delete the snapshot associated with an EBS volume mounted at /dev/sda1
```

So does this mean that this deletes only the snapshot of the root EBS volume? What about the snapshots of other EBS volumes? How do I delete them?

Or have I got the concept of snapshots completely wrong? Will there be only one snapshot for all the EBS backed devices?

Answer (score 0):

If, when you originally registered the AMI, you supplied a `snapshot_id` parameter to use as the root device for the image, the `delete_snapshot` parameter on `unregister_image` allows you to optionally delete this snapshot when the AMI is unregistered.

What other "snapshots associated with" the AMI do you want to delete?

Comment: Well, I have never had any other device other than the root as EBS backed volume. But I'm assuming you can create other devices as EBS backed volumes too. So when you create an AMI, EC2 will be automatically creating snapshots of all these devices which are EBS. When I delete an AMI, I want to delete all these snapshots which were created when that particular AMI was created.

Comment: I've never done it but I see no reason why you couldn't call ``create_image`` with a block device mapping structure that creates a number of volumes all created from snapshots.  In that case, boto would currently delete only the snapshot associated with the root volume (if the ``delete_snapshot`` parameter is True) but it could certainly do the same with the other snapshot ID's in the block device mapping.  You could also do that in your own code, of course.  You could create an issue for boto to have it do this.

Comment: @gamaat thanks for your reply. I didn't know that EBS and block devices were the same. I could get all the EBS backed devices for an iamge using image.block_device_mapping.